# Prettify a CodeEffect rule clause automatically

Tags: rule-engine, business-rules, codeeffects

Is there a way to prettify the rule clause automatically?

For example, automatically format a rule from this:

```
Check if A is equal to B or ( B contains abc and C is not equal to A ) or ( C has no value and ( A starts with xyz or A doesn't end with opq ))
```

To this:

```
Check if
    A is equal to B 
 or (     B contains abc 
      and C is not equal to A 
    ) 
 or (     C has no value 
      and (    A starts with xyz 
            or A doesn't end with opq 
          )
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do rule formatting automatically in the current version. But rule authors can use the included keyboard and gestures support; it's quite intuitive and easy to use. Details can be found [here](https://codeeffects.com/Doc/Business-Rule-Editor-Keyboard-Gestures-Support)